# reset value of c# variable from javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a variable `_count` in codebehind and accessing it from aspx page as below

```
 var result='<%=_count%>';
```

Now I want to reset this value from aspx page
I tried this but its not working

```
'<%=_count%>'=0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not reset the value of `asp.net` server side `veraible` from javascript until you do `postback` or sent `async` call. The code is translated by asp.net on server side and generated `html/javascript` is sent to client (browswer) Javascript can not access asp.net variables directly. You can assign changed value to `hidden` field and access that field on server side on postback.

*Html*

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdn" />
```

*Javascript*

```
document.getElementById('hdn').value = "123";
```

*Code behind*

```
_count = int.Parse(hdn.Value);
```